# Fastest way to save/read billions of 20bits numbers to/from magnetic disk

Tags: vba

I have billions of integer pairs of numbers to save/read to binary file on disk, and to elaborate as "long" for best speed.
All the numbers are in the range 1 to 999999 (decimal), therefore they fits in 20bits.

With performance as first goal and 100MBytes/sec disk speed, and saving/reading in big chunks of >1GB, which method do you expect to be the fastest?

A) save/read each of them as original 32bit long
B) save/read them converting them in set of three to/from 64bit longlong? (20+20+20 fitted in 64 bits)

I suppose that:
A) would require more disk saving/reading time
B) would require much CPU time for the conversions

PS: I use VBA but I suppose that the thing is almost the same for all the languages

Comment: Seems like you could run a test and figure that out for sure?

Comment: @TimWilliams I still don't even know how how to do the conversions.  This is to understand if it's worth spending some hours in studying how to do the conversions

Comment: These are *ridiculously* cheap conversions.

Comment: I think as a rule of thumb disk access is a lot more time-consuming than calculating something.

Comment: @ScottHunter what do you mean by "cheap"?

Comment: cheap = requiring almost *no* CPU time.

Comment: From a rough test with my Core I5 notebook CPU I measured about 40 millions of conversions per second, while the disk can write/read about 25 millions of long or 12.5 millions of longlong per second.  Fast conclusion: there's not a clear winner method.

Comment: I bet the difference would be more dramatic w/ a C program; depends (in part) on how you're doing the "conversions".

Comment: @ScottHunter I just measured a loop of 40 millions of "clng(currencyValue)" and it took 1.3sec vs 0.3sec of the empty loop.   I did this supposing that the final custom conversion function time would be equal or worse than this native simple "clng".